# How to read a .seq file from s3 in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am trying to a .seq file from s3. When I try to read it using

```
sc.textFile("s3n://logs/box316_0.seq").take(5).foreach(println)
```

it outputs -

```
    SEQorg.apache.hadoop.io.Text"org.apache.hadoop.io.BytesWritable'org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.GzipCodecp
```

and then a bunch of encoded characters. What format is that and How should I go about decoding this file ? My first time with hadoop so please be generous :)

Update :  I tried

```
sc.sequenceFile[Text,BytesWritable]("s3n://logs/box316_0.seq").take(5).foreach(println)
```

So the data is Json blob stored in sequence file and it gives me -

```
 Serialization stack: - object not serializable 
(class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: 5) - 
field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object) 
- object (class scala.Tuple2, (5,7g 22 73 69 6d 65 43 74 71 9d 90 92 3a .................. – user1579557 5 mins ago
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try:

```
val path = "s3n://logs/box316_0.seq"
val seq = sc.sequenceFile[LongWritable,BytesWritable](path)
val usableRDD = seq.map({case (_,v : BytesWritable) =>  Text.decode(v.getBytes))
```

Answer (score 0):

With sequence files you have to be aware of the types. It appears your is Text,BytesWritable. Try this:

```
sc.sequenceFile[Text,BytesWritable]("s3n://logs/box316_0.seq").take(5).foreach(println)
```

Comment: Thanks. So the data is a json blob. So it gives me following msg -  Serialization stack:
 - object not serializable (class: org.apache.hadoop.io.Text, value: 5)
 - field (class: scala.Tuple2, name: _1, type: class java.lang.Object)
 - object (class scala.Tuple2, (5,7g 22 73 69 6d 65 43 74 71 9d 90 92 3a ..................

Answer (score 0):

We came across this issue so often that we went ahead and built a solution around it. We call it readSEQ. This lets you read the sequence files out to either Parquet, AVRO, or JSON.

http://www.intricity.com/readseq/